# Wordpress Ajax in multisite template

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to use ajax in one of my wordpress templates. In my functions.php I added the following code.

```
function wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_ajax_call()
{

    // generate the response
    $response = json_encode( array( 'success' => true ) );

    // response output
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_ajax_call', 'my_special_ajax_call');
```

In My template I am calling this

```
jQuery('#category_id').change(function(){
    jQuery.get('/my_wordpress_folder/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',    {action:'my_special_ajax_call'},function(response,status){ alert(response);alert(status);
    jQuery('select#subcategory_id').html(result);
    });
```

});

But I am getting -1 as response.

The site is multisite wordpress.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns -1 because you are calling it in wrong way. Change the function name to "my_special_ajax_call"

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the function name from `wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_ajax_call` to `my_special_ajax_call`

the call back in the add action needs to be the name of the function that does the ajax